# insertAdjacentHTML is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, electron

So Im working with electron and in my file "ipcRendererEvent.js" I wrote the following code:

```
function loadImages (images) {
  const imagesList = document.querySelectorAll('ul.list-group')

  for (let i = 0, length1 = images.length; i < length1; i++) {
    const node = `<li class="list-group-item">
                    <img class="media-object pull-left" src="${images[i].src}" height="32">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <strong>${images[i].filename}</strong>
                      <p>${images[i].size}</p>
                    </div>
                  </li>`
    imagesList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', node)
  }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: imagesList.insertAdjacentHTML is not a function
    at loadImages (ipcRendererEvents.js:22)
    at EventEmitter._electron.ipcRenderer.on (ipcRendererEvents.js:58)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182)
```

Comment: `insertAdjacentHTML()` must be called on a *single* element if I'm not mistaken. You're trying to call it on the entire list.

Comment: Provide an example of `images`

Answer (score 8):

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). You could use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead to get the first matching element in the document or you can call [`insertAdjacentHtml`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) on an individual element in the list (e.g.: `imagesList[0].insertAdjacentHTML`).

Answer (score 1):

The correct notation is `insertAdjacentHTML`. You have a small typo :)